# Problem with controller after logging the Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't use the controller after logging to the session.

I tried to use `ViewBag` or `Tempdata` for my View. I have function `login` that looks like this,

```cs
HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", user.Email);
return View("Panel");
```

And panel

```
public IActionResult Panel()
{
  TempData["test"] = "test";
  ViewBag.test = "test";
  return View();
}
```

When I try to display `test` variable in view

```
<p>@TempData["test"]</p>
@ViewBag.test
```

it doesn't work. The Controller method works when i go directly to `Panel` function without logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a typo... you should use `RedirectToAction` to run the `Panel` action. Here you are returning the View without executing the appropriate action.

```
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", user.Email);
              return RedirectToAction("Panel");
```

BUT

In case this doesn't work, First of all, Install NuGet package to support the session: 
`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session` to support the Session behavior. You'll also need to register the service in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.